# Relation between weight subspaces of an $L$-module and universal enveloping algebras of Cartan subalgebras.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, lie-algebras

I have the setup:

$L$ is a finite dimensional semisimple Lie algebra over an algebraically closed field $F$ of characteristic $0$ and $H$ a Cartan subalgebra of $L$.

So I'm trying to work out this problem:

> Let $V$ be an infinite dimensional simple $L$-module. Prove: $V$ has a non-zero weight space if and only if dim$U(H).v < \infty$ for all $v\in V$.

Assuming $V$ has a non-zero weight space, then the sum of weight spaces $V' = \sum_{\lambda \in H^{*}}V_\lambda$ is a submodule of $V$. This means that
$V'=V$ since $V$ is simple and at least one weight space is non-zero. So all elements $v\in V$ is a sum of weight vectors, i.e. I should be able to determine dim$U(H).v$ by considering $U(H).v_\lambda$ for the weight vectors.

I don't really know how to proceed from here. The universal enveloping algebra is still quite confusing to me. I know how to pass from $L$-modules to $U(L)$-modules and see their action, but how do I pass from $U(L)$-modules to $U(H)$-modules? If that is even what I need.

Some help would be greatly appreciated, I feel quite stuck.

Comment: $U(H)$ is just a polynomial algebra over some basis $h_1, \ldots, h_n$ of the Cartan $H$. I think you are almost done for the forward direction: any vector $v$ is expressed as a finite sum of weight vectors, and the action of $H$ preserves the finite-dimensional sum of weight spaces that $v$ lives in.

Comment: @Joppy Could you expand a bit on how $U(H)$ is a polynomial algebra? I haven't heard that before and can't really see it.